# html append to already appended div does not work with appendTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

i have an appended div, what i want is to append a div with the appended one.
please see the [codepen of my code](https://codepen.io/ZinebS/pen/XaddRx) which is well explained with comments.

here is the structure i want: 
DIV 1 --> DIV 2(append with div1) --> DIV 3(Append to already appended Div 2)
i tried to use appendTo(); and also `$('#clsDashRegion_levelThree').find('#clsDashRegion_siteAlmCriticite').append(infoRegionSiteCriDetails);` but it does not work. if you can help me please make it work, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest the code is quite bad. There are much better ways to accomplish what you want, but nevertheless here is your fiddle slightly modified. **Please tell me if the behavior is what you want:**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OjNXWv

One important thing is that the `id` in the second div that you want to be clickable does not receive direct `events` because it was `generated dynamically`. So you have to use `event delegation` like so:

```
$(document).on('click','#clsDashRegion_siteAlmCriticite',function() { ...
```

Comment: You're welcome :-). You could have a look at clone() in the jQuery documentation and see if that can help you. And in general, do think so complicated. Your code really reflects how you want to achieve things, but there are easier ways. My advice: Read the documentation (https://api.jquery.com/) so you get an overview of what jQuery is capable to do. It helped me a lot when I started.

Comment: Try insertAfter() instead of appendTo() to insert it AFTER the second div. And for the second question: You can find millions of examples for one-time-clicks :-) I'm sure you'll find one

Answer (score 0):

After the

```
$('#clsDashRegion_levelTwo').html(infoRegionCriticite);
  });
```

Shouldn't you then call

```
levelThreeCriticiteDetailsBloc()
```

Otherwise when you click '#clsDashRegion_siteAlmCriticite' nothing will happen.

Comment: You shouldn't call it then. You are calling it before the element exists, so there is nothing it can do.

Comment: Housham the alert inside the function works but stil i do not get the append result...